# Adding string in front and at end of a list

Tags: c#, .net

I have list of names:

```
IEnumerable<Name> names;
names = n.GetNames(abc);
```

It gets list like: Ken, John, Sam,... I want it to show like this:
'Ken', 'John', 'Sam',...

I tried this:
`string s = string.Join("',", names);` but it gives result like:
Ken', John', Sam',...

Is there a way to add "'" in front of these names in single line of code?

Answer (score 3, accepted):

Try this.

```
string s = string.Join(",", names.Select(s => string.Format("'{0}'", s)).ToArray());
```

Comment: Your solution works great. Just missing ) and ToArray i updated it above. Thanks for the solution!

Comment: @NoviceMe that's because you run .NET < 4.0, with .NET 4.0 you can call `string.Join` with `IEnumerable<string>`...

Comment: @NoviceMe check the first parameter to `Join`.

Answer (score 3):

I think you were almost there:

```
string s = "'" + string.Join("','", names) + "'";
```

Comment: This will fail however when `names.Length == 0` ;p

Comment: Of all solutions, mine was the laziest! =D

Comment: Also, the most efficient as long as you add a check for the array length.